# Differentiation under integral sign help

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Question is: If $$f(a)= \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\cdot \cos(at)~dt$$ then I have to show that $f'(a)=-\dfrac{a}{2}\cdot f(a)$.

I know that $\displaystyle\frac{d}{da}f(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial{a}}(\cos(at))\cdot e^{-t^{2}}~dt=-a\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\sin(at)~dt$ . How to finish it off from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because
$$f'(a)=\dfrac{d}{da}f(a)=-\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}t\sin{(at)}dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{(at)}d(\dfrac{1}{2}e^{-t^2})=-\dfrac{a}{2}f(a)$$

Comment: I stil dont get it. How come $\sin(at)\cdot d(1/2 e^{-t^{2}} = -\frac{a}{2}f(a)$?

Comment: i think  i have to apply integration by parts. I se it now thanks.

Comment: Now to evaluate (1) we use  ILATE, that is integration by parts rule. Our choice $u=\sin(zt) \implies du = \cos(zt) \cdot z \ dt $ and $dv = e^{-t^{2}} \cdot t \implies v = -\frac{e^{-t^{2}}}{2}$. So then 

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^{2}}\cdot t \cdot \sin(zt) \ dt &= u\cdot v - \int v\cdot du \\ &= \Bigl[\frac{e^{-t^{2}}}{2}\cdot\sin(zt)\Bigr]_{0}^{\infty} + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t^{2}}}{2}\cdot z \cdot \cos(zt) \ dt\\ &= 0 + \frac{z}{2} \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^{2}} \cdot \cos(zt) \ dt \\ &= \frac{z}{2} \cdot I(z)
\end{align*}